# pm2 crashing while loading bots. Is there anyway to add orphaned process back to it?

Tags: python, process, pm2

Basically the title.  We use pm2 for process management for our bots in the server, of which there are many.  As of the last reboot, I found that pm2 has been failing during reboot with the following message in the logs:

```
process could not be forked properly, check your system health
```

PM2 crashes after this, but the bot processes are still running.  Is there anyway to upload those processes to a new pm2 process without having to go to each process, kill it, and reboot that bot?  If I have 100 bots, that becomes impossible to handle.

Comment: PM2 does not provide such feature.  I am not sure if it maintains a list of active processes and their meta data somewhere. If it does, then custom solution would be needed as there is no public API for that

Comment: You need to define restart strategy in pm2. which can does graceful process stop and restart entire process.